# Differentiate between two submit buttons in a form using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms

How can I find out which submit button was clicked in javascript?

```
function submitForm(){
   //if find open popup
   //else if add continue in the same window

}

<form action="/findNames" onsubmit="return submitForm()">
    <input type="submit" value="Add" onclick="submitForm(this)"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Find" onclick="submitForm(this)"/>
</form>
```

---

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

I tried to do it with onclick instead as follows but when the "Find" button is clicked it opens a popup window and submits the parent window as well. How can I stop it from submitting the parent window?

```
function submitForm(submit){
    if(submit.value=="Find"){
        find();//opens a popup window
    }else if(submit.value == "Add"){
        //stay in the same window
    } 
}

function find(){
    var width  = 1010;
    var height = 400;           
    var params = 'width='+width+', height='+height;     
    popupWin = window.open('find.do','windowname5', params);
    popupWin.focus();
}

<form action="/findNames">
    <input type="submit" value="Add" onclick="submitForm(this)"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Find" onclick="submitForm(this)"/>
</form>
```

Comment: Not sure about it, but did you try to add `name` attribute to the `input` tag?

Comment: Why you don't split it in two forms ?

Comment: @piokuc I did but how do you access the name attribute value in javascript?

Comment: You should look into using event listeners to pick up your click events instead of binding your function calls inline (which is deprecated).

Comment: you can access the form, input tags and their attributes via DOM, I just did a google search "how do you access the name attribute value in javascript@ and there was a few pages discussing it

Comment: @MikeB Nothing could be farther from the truth. Event-handler attributes are standards-compliant and work "always"; event listeners do not "always" work (the API is dependent on the DOM implementation). HTML5 even introduced new event-handler attributes, so how can they be deprecated? Do not jump the "Unobtrusive JavaScript" train, it is run by wannabes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are on the right track, but your form is submitted always because you are not canceling the events (or, in DOM Level 2+ parlance, you are not “preventing the default action for the event”).

```
function submitForm (button)
{
  if (button.value == "Find")
  {
    /* open popup */
    find();
  }
  else if (button.value == "Add")
  {
    /* stay in the same window */
  } 

  return false;
}

<form action="/findNames">
  <input type="submit" value="Add" onclick="return submitForm(this)"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Find" onclick="return submitForm(this)"/>
</form>
```

(You should never name a form-related variable `submit` because if you are not careful that overrides the `form` object's `submit` method.)

The return value `false`, when returned to the event handler, prevents the default action for the `click` event.  This means the user agent works as if the submit button was never activated in the first place, and the form is not submitted.

Another approach to solve this is to save a value identifying the clicked submit button in a variable or property, and check that value in the `submit` event listener.  This works because the `click` event of the `input` (submit button) by definition happens before the `submit` event of the `form`:

```
var submitName;

function submitForm (form)
{
  if (submitName == "Find")
  {
    /* open popup */
    find();
  }
  else if (submitName == "Add")
  {
    /* stay in the same window */
  } 

  return false;
}

function setSubmit (button)
{
  submitName = button.value;
}

<form action="/findNames" onsubmit="return submitForm(this)">
  <input type="submit" value="Add" onclick="setSubmit(this)"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Find" onclick="setSubmit(this)"/>
</form>
```

(This is just an example.  Try to minimize the number of global variables.)

Again, the return value `false`, when returned to the `submit` event handler, prevents the form from being submitted.  You may want to return `true` instead if you explicitly want the form to be submitted after you handled the `submit` event.  For example, you may want to validate the form and if validation was successful, display the server response in another frame, through the `target` attribute.

The advantage of event-handler attributes over adding event listeners in script code is that it is runtime-efficient, backwards-compatible, and still standards-compliant.  The disadvantage is that you may have to duplicate event-handler code if the event does not bubble.  (Not an issue here.)

Other people may say that a disadvantage of event-handler attributes is also that there is no separation between markup and function; however, you should make up your own mind about that. In my opinion, function is always tied to specific markup, and the jumping through hoops for working around different DOM implementations is seldom worth it.

See also: [DOM Client Object Cross-Reference: DOM Events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM_Client_Object_Cross-Reference/DOM_Events)

The most important thing here is that, regardless of all client-side improvements that you make, the form stays accessible, i. e. that it still works with the keyboard even without client-side scripting.  Your server-side script (here: `/findNames`) can work as fallback, then, and the client-side script can avoid unnecessary roundtrips, improving the user experience and reducing the network and server load.

Answer (score 7):

An `input` of `type="submit"` will always submit the form. Use an `input` of `type="button"` instead to create a button that doesn't submit.

Comment: I initially had one of them as a button. This form has a lot of input fields and my problem is I need to submit the values in these input fields to the server, when I click the button

Comment: According to [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_name.asp) only `input` tags with a `name` attribute will have their values submitted to the server.

Comment: @Kninnug W3Schools is junk, but correct in this case. However, that the *form control's value* is not submitted does _not_ mean that the *form* is not submitted. IOW, the form is submitted anyway.

Comment: When you click a button instead of a "submit", the input values do not get submitted. How can I make it submit all the inputs in the form, even if you click this "button"?

Comment: @PointedEars fair point, but Susie, what exactly do you want now? Must the form be submitted in both the Add and the Find case?

Comment: @Kninnug Yes, I was trying to do that

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? Your original question states you want to stop the Find button from submitting the parent window. Do you want it to submit to the popup instead?

Answer (score 3):

Your code should be refactored to properly attach event listeners.

First, define your functions that will serve as listeners:

```
function preventSubmission(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
    return false;
}

function find(){
    var width  = 1010;
    var height = 400;           
    var params = 'width='+width+', height='+height;     
    popupWin = window.open('find.do','windowname5', params);
    popupWin.focus();
}
```

Then, cache references to the relevant form elements:

```
var form = document.getElementById('my-form'),
    findButton = document.getElementById('find');
```

And finally, add the listeners to the DOM events:

```
if (form.addEventListener) {
    form.addEventListener("submit", preventSubmission);
    findButton.addEventListener("click", find);
} else {
    form.attachEvent("submit", preventSubmission);
    findButton.attachEvent("click", find);
}
```

Here's a full working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/CQAHv/2/

Comment: Wrong: −1. Explicit event listeners are not required (they are implicit with event-handler attributes), and [`attachEvent` is _not_ equivalent to `addEventListener`](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/08/addevent_consid.html).

Comment: Yes but inline html event handlers are considered bad practice.

Comment: Also, I am aware attachEvent and addEventListener are not the same: **hence the conditional statement**. [IE8 and below need attachEvent.](http://www.sacoskun.com/2012/11/difference-between-addeventlistener-and.html)

Comment: No, they are not “considered bad practice”; you have been listening to the wrong people. And you are not aware of the differences. IE8 and below do _not_ need `attachEvent`, they can work like any other DOM 0 browser (down to Netscape 3.0). Avoid `attachEvent` unless there is an MSHTML-*specific* reason to use it.

Comment: "In Internet Explorer versions prior to IE 9, [you have to use attachEvent rather than the standard addEventListener.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/EventTarget.addEventListener#Compatibility)"

Comment: AISB, that statement is insufficient at best; you may want to read it *in context*. Internet Explorer, and the MSHTML DOM, has always supported and is still supporting the `on…` properties of “DOM Level 0”, and the corresponding event-handler attributes. In fact, IIRC it was Microsoft who first added new event-handler attributes, like `onbeforeprint`, to those they borrowed from Netscape.

Comment: The _context_ is production-quality code, thus the importance of [separating behavior from markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript). AISB, inline event handlers are considered [bad](http://alistapart.com/article/behavioralseparation) [practice](http://www.webstandards.org/action/dstf/manifesto/). The DOM Level 0 model is outmoded and only allows one event handler per event which will cause problems in larger projects.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28120/discussion-between-pointedears-and-chrx)

Comment: Despite *possible* disadvantages – that "Unobtrusive JavaScript" *also* has, but those are of course not as loudly communicated – new event-handler attributes are defined in HTML5. What does this teach you?

Answer (score 2):

Check this out:

**Javascript**:

```
var clicked;
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

for(var i = 0; i < buttons.length;i++)
{
    var elem = buttons[i];
    if(elem.type=="submit")
    {
        elem.addEventListener("click", function(){ clicked=this.value;}, false);
    }
}


window.onsubmit = function(e)
{
   alert(clicked);
    return false;
}
```

**Markup**:

```
<form action="/findNames">
    <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    <input type="submit" value="Find" />
</form>
```

You will have the value of whatever button was clicked.

**jsFiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/v9Sz2/

**Note**: For testing purposes I have the `return false` inside the `onsubmit` event. The first jsFiddle sample has its own `window.onload` included, so you may want to add everything that's not inside the `window.onsubmit` inside `window.onload`, like this http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/v9Sz2/1/ (Tested in Chrome, Firefox).

Comment: Adding properties to `window` is worse enough, but really, `window.onsubmit`? The `submit` event does not bubble everywhere.

Comment: What do you mean it does not bubble everywhere? This solution works across multiple browsers, and window.onsubmit is totally valid in this context.