# In Servlet, differentiate between two buttons that submit the form

Tags: jsp, servlets

In my jsp, I have two buttons that submit the form. The action of the form redirects to a servlet. I want, in my servlet, to know which button has been pressed. Is there a way to differentiate between the two buttons ?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11830351/multiple-submit-buttons-in-the-same-form-calling-different-servlets

Comment: This post may help also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15975810/differentiate-between-two-submit-buttons-in-a-form-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

The name of the submit button that is clicked is included as part of the request data.

So:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit1"/>
<input type="submit" name="submit2"/>
```

If you were to click on one of these, then you get, effectively, `submit1=` or `submit2=` as a query parameter in the request. You'll only get the one that is clicked, not the other. You can test the existence of the value in the payload, even though it will have no actual value associated with it.

Comment: I have <button> as tags and not <input>, Could I do the same thing ? and could you tell me wow could I recover the name exactly ?